# What is the '+' symbol mean in a chord?

Tags: chords, notation, chord-theory

When I played a music meet a D+9 and a A7/5+. I have tried search in google, but didn't find it. Does anybody know that?

Comment: +1, as I've not seen either. D+9 could be D,F#,A,C,E#. Or D,F#,A#,C,E. A7/5+ could be A,C#,E#,G, maybe 'cos the slash is there, with the E# in the bass. Please post the section in question, there may be clues.

Answer (score 13):

It has two different meanings in the context  of chords . Traditionally, the '+' symbol is used to denote an [augmented triad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_triad), however it is also used to represent a raised interval which is typically represented by a sharp (#).

The first one is most likely an augmented triad with a 9th. The second one just treat the '+' as a sharp where you would play an A7 with a #5.

Comment: A third, admittedly far less common, meaning is a microtonal accidental indicating to raise a pitch by a syntonic comma, or about 21.5 cents. Used by a number of extended just intonation composers like Ben Johnston. Obviously not what the OP was asking about, but it is an intriguing alternate meaning of the symbol.

Comment: At the risk of getting obnoxious, the "+" symbol actually has *many* meanings in music, such as LH pizzicato and stopped horn.

Comment: A futher meaning, especially encountered in baroque music, is an unspecific ornamentation (instead e.g. of a trill symbol).

Comment: In rock guitar we often use the term "E add 9" which might look like E+9 which typically ends up being a power chord with a 2nd added.

Comment: @rcd add chords are **never** represented by a +. http://www.guitar-chord.org/add9.html

Comment: @rcd - read my answer below. Add and + are very different, even in rock guitar.

Comment: @tim and Dom Incorrect.  There are at least five different answers above, and no consensus (the page Dom sent only shows what an add9 *is*.  As jjmusicnotes wrote, it can have many meanings, and it has most certainly been written that way in tablature etc.

Comment: @rcd the find an example using the + to represent an add chord. No one **ever** represents it as a + because that is the traditional symbol for an augmented chord.

Comment: @rcd - consensus doesn't have to come into it. The OP is asking about chords, not tab.I've only ever seen it PROPERLY used as aug.Please show examples, I love to be proved wrong!

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - at the risk of being pedantic, the question only relates to chords. Yes, you're right, but...Please help, there are one or two misguided ideas here.

Comment: @rcd Tim and Dom are both correct here, unfortunately you are incorrect. As it pertains to chords, "+" is for augmented triads / intervals / or in rarer cases, chord tones. In **no way** is it used in a scholar-accepted analytical system to represent "add" chords, which may be noted by saying "add" or "( )", as in "Em7(11)". An E9 chord is *not* a "power chord" unless you specifically omit the 3rd and 7th chord tones. Remember that TAB notation was developed by people and for people unable to read traditional music notation.

Answer (score 4):

It's an augmented triad, played by sharpening the fifth by a semitone.

Answer (score 1):

+= sharpened. Sharpened whatever. The number that has + in front of it(or by it) is raised by one semitone so +5 is a sharpened 5th and +9 is a sharpened 9th. The sign means augmented,when used in chord names, and the usual note that's augmented (taken up by a semitone) is the 5th. Thus A = A,C#,E, whereas A+ = A,C#,E#(F). It's common in jazz to alter 5ths and 9ths, so there is also an augmented 9th. Sometimes labelled +9, or aug9.

Note that '+' is different from 'add', even if it has the same connotation in maths.

Comment: I was tempted to down vote, when I realized you were correct... Perhaps a rewording would help, as I was initially responding to the first two short sentences without reading on.

Comment: Thanks for that! I sometimes feel we have some fickle readers, so, yes, it would be prudent... Be interesting if the downvoters read the edit, too...

Comment: I've never seen the + used in the context of #9.  For example I see A#9(b5) but never A+9(b5) though in this context there would be no confusion.  I have thus far in my life only seen the + refer to augmenting the 5th.  Can you cite an example of your use?

Comment: @ggcg - no, but I use it all the time, and have done for 20 odd yrs.Let's face it - what else *could* it be?

Comment: Love to find out dv reason! Probably 'I don't understand this'.

Answer (score 0):

It means either forget about the fifth and make the fifth sharp instead when it's added after the base chord, or make the note a half step higher when it's added to the chord.

Comment: I've never seen + interpreted as forget about the 5th.  Can you cite a reference, a theory book?

Answer (score -3):

I think the answer is much simpler than all the things everyone is saying as far as popular music charts. What I have seen is that a D+9 chord is a D F# A and an E on top differing from a D9 chord which is a7th chord which is 
D F# A C E. An A7/5+ is something I have not seen. If they are saying play a 5th in the bass then they are saying add the E in the bass which is the fifth of an A chord. The+ plus may be simply to add the fifth. A + sign to me is just saying add one more note not add all the thirds up to that note.

Comment: This is completely wrong. The chord you describe as D F♯ A E is a **Dadd9**. Nobody who understands how to name chords _ever_ writes this as **D+9**; it doesn't matter what kind of music you are talking about. **+** _never_ means add a note in a chord name. It either indicates an augmented triad, or a sharped note. The answers and comments above make this clear.

Comment: It's an augmented chord.  I think you may want to delete your answer.